# Calculating the how often an element of an array falls within a certain range

Tags: python, arrays

Basically I'm attempting a question given to me by one of my peers to help me with python. I've got to calculate how often a given value falls within a certain distance from the 'edge' of the array.

I've generated a 100x100 array filled with random variables by using rand(100,100). However from there I'm pretty stumped.

As far as I can work out I've got to declare the range and then use counters to count the elements within that range, but I honestly don't have a clue.

Comment: What did you try, can you quote your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what's meant by "within a certain distance from the 'edge' of the array", but am assuming that you have a numpy array and that you are trying to count the number of occurrences within an upper and lower bound, in which case you can use:

```
((lowerBound < numpyArray) & (numpyArray < upperBound)).sum()
```

where:

lowerBound and upperBound are float variables between 0 and 1

numpyArray is the array that you have generated